# Upload form not working on firefox,edge but working on chrome

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

Upload form not working on firefox,edge but working in chrome i tried a lot but i couldn't find what is the issue.
The code works well on chrome and android browser but doesn't support on firefox.

```
Here is the code.

    $("#fimg").submit(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
      if($("#file").val()!=''){
            $.ajax({
                url: "<URL TO PHP>",
                type: "POST",
                data:  new FormData(this),
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData:false,
                success: function(data)
                {
                    //Okay!!
                },
                error: function() 
                {
                //error.
                }           
           });

           }else{
          //No Image Selected!
           }

        });

PHP:

        if(isset($_POST['go'])&&$_POST['go']=="Upload"){

         //Returns the uploaded path.

          }
```

Comment: Without a 'working' example it will be hard to tell what's going on. You assume the error is somewhere in the code you selected for us, but is it? Try <F12> in Firefox and debug.

Comment: Did you search on google. There are a lot of similar questions here and a lot of tutorials how to do it correctly. https://www.google.nl/#q=ajax+upload+form+only+works+on+chrome

Answer (score 1):

Debugging the script with the help of firefox helped.
The problem is with the php code.

**Firefox returned the following headers.**

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="13347014_844904292319754_6605126991244883708_n.jpg"

**Chrome returned the following headers.**

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="13347014_844904292319754_6605126991244883708_n.jpg"

Content-Type: image/jpeg
------WebKitFormBoundaryC1UNyDWNSBtzAMQt

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="go"

Insert

changing the `isset($_POST['go'])&&$_POST['go']=="Upload"` to

```
if(isset($_POST)){
```

worked.
Anyways thank you guys.